# In sun-web.xml we need to map the roles sepecified in web.xml to a group?

Tags: java, security, spring-security, glassfish, jaas

> In **sun-web.xml** we need to map the roles specified in **web.xml** to a
>   group

1. Is it true for all server or just for GlassFish?
2. Why we need to do that?
3. In some of the example on JAAS or authentication I haven't seen this step, What are the cases where it can be skipped?
4. Is there any other `file name` used instead of sun-web.xml? and **why** alternate name?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-security, declaring Role in spring context file will be sufficient. If you want to take benefit of spring's default implementation start your role name with 'ROLE' prefix.